# Should I use Parcelable in this use case?

Tags: android, design-patterns, parcelable

I'm developing an Android app. I have this domain class:

```
public class Film implements Parcelable {

    private List<FavChangesListener> listeners;
    //more members

}
```

I'm showing a films list and each item has a button to mark/unmark a film as favorite. Another components in the app listen to this fav status change.

```
public interface FavChangesListener {
    void onFavChanged(Film film);
}
```

When you tap on a film, another activity is shown with that film's detail. Once inside the detail activity, you also can mark/unmark the film as favorite and the listeners have to be notified, same as before.

So far, so good. Problem is that I'm passing the film between the list activity and the detail activity using an extra: my `Film` class implements `Parcelable`. So the listeners list is null (or empty) when the film is deserialized in detail activity.

- Should I use another way to pass the film between activities instead of extra+Parcelable solution? Like using a third component to set/get the film.
- Should I make the listener implements Parcelable and serialize the list inside the extra? (I'm sure not)
- Is it a good idea in this case to have listeners inside the domain class?

Advices and suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: why do you need to pass `FavChangesListener` ? You should pass `DAO` between activities.

Comment: "Is it a good idea in this case to have listeners inside the domain class?" -- no. That is the role of a presenter or controller. The domain model should be close to a pure POJO.

Comment: Thank you :) I will change my design and will remove the listeners from Film class.